# Is it possible to retrieve Android Shared Preferences in Xamarin that were stored in Java

Tags: java, android, xamarin, mobile, sharedpreferences

I have an Android app that was previously written in Java and used SharedPreferences to store some details. This app was left dormant for a number of years and wasn't updated with framework updates. So, when it came to updating it the decision was made to re-write it using Xamarin. The app was written with the same package name and details so it could be built and rolled out as an update to the current app.

Now... What I'd like to do if possible, is retrieve the SharedPreferences stored to the phone in the java version of the app for use in the Xamarin version of the app.

I have the original code so I know what they were naming the Store and the variables. I have the old app installed on a device and have stored some details by using the app.

I have also added the necessary code to the new Xamarin app to get the shared preferences and debugged this on the same device. However, I'm not getting any values returned, just the default values defined.

What I'd like to know is if anyone has been able to do this before or if what I'm trying is not possible since we're crossing languages now.

I assumed the latter however I wasn't going to give up without first trying and asking the community.

Any thoughts or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think yes, but you always can try it by yourself, install the Java app on device save some prefs then update with the Xamarin version and try to see what you have inside the storage.

Comment: I have done that, not able to retrieve them so far. Not sure on the issue so I wanted to pose the question.

Comment: When you install the new Xamarin version on the phone it is replacing the old app?

Comment: Think so, only way to prove it working was to comit the change, create a build, submit it to an internal track on the app store then update OTA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The shared preference file is just XML.  There's nothing special about what language is used to read or write it.

Comment: That's what I was hoping however I can't see any files stored in a folder for the old app despite it using Shared Preferences. It is currently using SDK 16 though...

Comment: Issue was that I needed to create a new version, release it to internal through Google Play and update OTA. Guessing trying to debug direct to device was wiping the old version and SharedPreferences.